# Django: How to fill inherited form fields from an instance of the base model class?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model `Customer`, which inherits from a User model, and adds a new field.

```
class Customer(User):
   customer_since: models.Datefield()
```

I then want to use use a generic view to create customers:

```
class CustomerCreate(CreateView):
    model = Customer
    form_class = CustomerForm
```

When I create a new customer, I want to use the data from `request.user` to autofill the form with the inherited fields. How can I do that?

I know that if I was creating the record manually, I would do it like this:

```
Customer.objects.create(user_ptr=request.user, customer_since=datetime.date.today())
```

but with a generic view, the form is generated automatically and saved by the form_valid method of the CreateView, how do I tell the form to include the proper user reference?

Comment: But you cant have a Customer with the same data as the User. Your Customer model is actually using the User table in the database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

Comment: the Customer model adds a new field (in this example)  to the base User model

Comment: What I mean is that is impossible to have a Customer with the same username as a User because both models will share the User table at DB level.

Comment: I see what you mean. I get that the Customer table will hold a foreign key to the User Table, but I want to tell the Form which user should be used for a new Customer.

Comment: add those fields in the Meta class 'fields' list of your CustomerForm. But I think you are getting into trouble if you want to *create* a customer with an existing user.

Comment: For the record, I gave up on using Inheritance and simply added a `OneToOneField` linking the tables. It works and its way simpler.